# JPEG source-code and quantization mode change - C language

Tags: c, jpeg, quantization, libjpeg-turbo

I'm assigned to do a project that consists in changing the quantization in the JPEG source-code, from the quantization tables to Lloyd-Max quantization. The problem is not knowing what to do (I know how to change the quantization), but where to find the code I'm suposed to change.
If someone is familiar with the *libjpeg-turbo*, could you give me some advice on doing so?

Answer (score 0):

I refrained from responding because it has been a long time since I have prowled around in the LIBJPEG code and I understand that it has been rewritten. The code functions well and is efficient but it is quite torturous to read and understand.

This is a C++ library that apparently was written for instructive purposes. For understandability it is about as good as you are going to get with JPEG:

http://www.colosseumbuilders.com/sourcecode/imagelib403.zip

However, if I remember correctly, this one, like LIbJPEG, combines some steps of the DCT and quantization.